# PHP get_headers() reports different headers than CURL

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

How is it possible that `get_headers()` could possibly return a different result than getting them by CURL? Here is my code:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
$url = 'http://www.foxbusiness.com/index.html';

echo "get_headers() headers:\n\n";
$headers = get_headers($url);
print_r($headers);

echo "\n\nCURL headers\n\n";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url ) );
$headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );
curl_close( $curl );
print_r($headers);
```

This is the result:

```
get_headers() headers:

Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
    [1] => Server: AkamaiGHost
    [2] => Mime-Version: 1.0
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html
    [4] => Content-Length: 283
    [5] => Expires: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 07:29:14 GMT
    [6] => Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 07:29:14 GMT
    [7] => Connection: close
)


CURL headers

Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: Apache
    [2] => X-FoxNews-EdgeTTL: 2m
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Cache-Control: max-age=64
    [5] => Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 07:29:14 GMT
    [6] => Connection: keep-alive
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
)
```

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I included the code above. I'm not sure how to tell what headers it sends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get_headers` will do a GET request by default while you configured cURL to do a HEAD request. Start by making the request identical to what cURL sends by putting a different [HTTP stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) [using HEAD for the request method.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#example-3797)

Also, the server seems to expect a User Agent, so make sure you either [provide `user_agent` in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) or add it to the stream context.

The following should work:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD',
            'user_agent' => "PHP"
        )
    )
);
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/cOO9XS

Note that `stream_context_set_default` modifies the global default Stream Context, so any calls to other methods using this stream wrapper will now do HEAD requests once you called the above. Unlike for example, `file_get_contents`, `get_headers` does not allow supplying a custom stream context via arguments to the function. In other words, make sure you change the method back to GET after you got the headers.

Comment: Where is the OP calling to example.com?

Answer (score 4):

Add a different User-Agent header before get_headers:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD',
            'header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1\r\n"
        )
    )
);
```

And, might as well specify HEAD since you only want headers.  With this change you get the right headers.

**OUTPUT**

```
get_headers() headers:

Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [1] => Server: Apache
    [2] => X-FoxNews-EdgeTTL: 2m
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Cache-Control: max-age=76
    [5] => Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 07:53:24 GMT
    [6] => Connection: close
)


CURL headers

Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: Apache
    [2] => X-FoxNews-EdgeTTL: 2m
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Cache-Control: max-age=76
    [5] => Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 07:53:24 GMT
    [6] => Connection: keep-alive
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
)
```