# get_headers() on Gravatar returning 200 instead of 404

Tags: php, http-headers, get-headers

I'm passing a URL that should generate a 404 Error, using PHP's `get_headers()`. In fact, if I use the URL as a link, I get a 404 Error in my browser. And if I use the URL (which is to an image file) as an img `src` the "Network" tab of my browser shows a 404 Error status. But when I `print_r` the results of `@get_headers( $uri )` I see that my response returns `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`! What's up with that?

Is this something on the web server itself? If so, what (if anything) should I communicate to the server support to get them to address the issue?

**Update**

The URL I am testing against is a gravatar URL: http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/4d445fd58bf07d406345bac336c3b836?s=96&d=404&r=G

Comment: It's possible that your browser is following a redirect while get_headers() is not.

Comment: @JRL in this case, a redirect will be a 3XX (302 for example), not a 200

Comment: can you give us the URI ?

Comment: @MatRT it's a gravatar URL, deliberately pointing to a user that does not exist, and passing the 404 default parameter. When you follow this link you will see a 404 error in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL that was being sent to `get_headers()` had html-escaped entities, specifically `&amp;` rather than an actual `&` ampersand token. **This makes a difference to `get_headers()`**, though its original use (`<img src='{$url}'... />`) didn't mind the html entities encoded version. The solution was simply to use `&` when building the URL.

*Specific Application for Checking the Validity of a Gravatar*

Since I encountered this in the context of checking the validity of a Gravatar, and the code that I was using was on some more-or-less "official" documentation, I'm posting this in case anyone else runs into the same issue and wants a cut-and-paste solution.

```
$url = "$host/avatar/";
$url .= $email_hash;
$url .= '?s='.$size;
$url .= '&d=404';

$gravatar_response_code = wp_cache_get( $email_hash );
if ( false === $gravatar_response_code ){
    $response = wp_remote_head ( $url );
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ){
        $gravatar_response_code = "error";
    } else {
        $gravatar_response_code = $response['response']['code'];
    }

    wp_cache_set( $email_hash, $gravatar_response_code, '', 300 );
}

if ( '200' == $gravatar_response_code )
    $avatar = "<img alt='{$safe_alt}' src='{$url}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
```

*Do note that certain functions `wp_cache_get()`, `wp_remote_head()` and `wp_cache_set()` are WordPress-specific functions. The `wp_remote_head()` method of the HTTP API will call `curl`, `get_headers()` or even `fopen()` depending on what's available so it's 100% relevant and exhibits the same behaviours as what's documented here.*

Answer (score 1):

I did a test and I get the 404 not 200.

```
  $url = 'http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/4d445fd58bf07d406345bac336c3b836?s=96&d=404&r=G';
  var_dump(get_headers($url, 0));
  /* array (size=11)
  0 => string 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' (length=22)
  1 => string 'Cache-Control: max-age=300' (length=26)
  2 => string 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' (length=38)
  3 => string 'Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 13:46:12 GMT' (length=35)
  4 => string 'Expires: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 13:51:12 GMT' (length=38)
  5 => string 'Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Sep 2012 05:18:58 GMT' (length=44)
  6 => string 'Server: nginx' (length=13)
  7 => string 'Via: 1.1 varnish' (length=16)
  8 => string 'X-Varnish: 3241507148 3241041069' (length=32)
  9 => string 'Content-Length: 13' (length=18)
  10 => string 'Connection: close' (length=17)
  */
```

I did a little search and it seems that the behaviour of get_headers() depends primarily on the PHP version.

However it can be changed by changing the HTTP context options (see: [HTTP context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php))

### Edit

Here's a very similar problem: [PHP get_headers() reports different headers than CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210816/php-get-headers-reports-different-headers-than-curl)

Comment: thanks for checking. I'm running from a local XAMPP installation. I wonder whether this is related?

Comment: Definitely, but indirectly. Each XAMPP, WAMP etc. comes with some PHP version and there were a couple of those lately. Check what version of the PHP you have on your XAMPP, try to check the link from my answer. There are at least two settings that may be interesting "follow_location" and "max_redirects".

Comment: thanks for the follow-up! I attempted to set the `stream_context_set_default()` as recommended in the linked SE question, but the results were identical. I'm having difficulty grokking the HTTP context options.

Comment: Can you post what have you tried (I mean a part of an actual code)? And possibly your PHP version?

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. The issue ended up being tangential, but your request to post the actual code led me to try out a few things as I was doing so, and that led to the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help, but I think that for the sake of all the other people who may have the similar issue you could provide the answer for your own question. :)
ps. Also I'm curious what was that

Comment: Okay, I've taken your advice and posted the results in an answer.